# php add key and value to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have this array

```
$additional = array();
```

And if i want to add new value and key to this array i use

```
$additional["key"] = "value";
```

now the problem on  multidimensional  array

```
while($condition){
$this->array[] = array(
  "key" => "value"
    );

   //how can i add some key and value to this array 
   if($x == 1){
     $this->array[]["newkey"] = "value"; 
    }

   }
```

> $this->array[]["newkey"] = "value";

i try this but its didn't work

Comment: Specify the index, like `array[0]['newkey'] = `

Comment: its while loop how can i know the index may i must define $i = 0; out side loop and increase every time did there are another idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delay adding the nested array to the main array:

```
while($condition){
    $item = array(
        "key" => "value"
    );

    if(x == 1){
        $item["newkey"] = "value"; 
    }
    // When all is ready:
    $this->array[] = $item;
}
```

Comment: that is what i want it nice answer :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use a incremential variable :

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while($condition){
  $this->array[$i] = array(
    "key" => "value"
  );

  //how can i add some key and value to this array 
  if(x == 1){
     $this->array[$i]["newkey"] = "value"; 
  }
  $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: its while loop how can i know the index may i must define $i = 0; out side loop and increase every time did there are another idea ?

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand the problem

Comment: no problem in your code but i want the best idea and trincot write it

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a index or key for multidimensional array.

For example you can add like;

```
$this->array[items]["newkey"] = "value";
```